# Receive broadcast packets from IP 255.255.255.255 in ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp, broadcast

I am currently struggling with receiving broadcast packets from the IP address 255.255.255.255 in ruby.

In general my network configuration has two different vlans:

- vlan10: ip 10.10.10.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 => broadcast address 10.10.255.255
- vlan20: ip 10.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 => broadcast address 10.255.255.255

As receiver I use the following test code to dispay the incoming packets:

```
require 'socket'
addr = ['0.0.0.0', 3020]
BasicSocket.do_not_reverse_lookup = true
# Create socket and bind to address
UDPSock = UDPSocket.new
UDPSock.bind(addr[0], addr[1])
while true
 data, addr = UDPSock.recvfrom(1024)
 puts "From addr: '%s', msg: '%s'" % [addr[0], data]
end
UDPSock.close
```

Receiving packets from 10.255.255.255 and 10.10.255.255 works fine.
Packets sent to IP 255.255.255.255 are not received.

Do I need to set additional properties to make ruby receive "limited broadcast" packets?

I hope somebody can help. I am really lost.

Thanks, Uwe

Comment: "*Packets sent to IP 255.255.255.255 are not received*" - make sure your network router is not blocking them.  Not all routers are configured to allow broadcasts to `255.255.255.255` to cross subnets by default. Using subnet-specific broadcast IPs is typically preferred over using the all-subnets `255.255.255.255` IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. During checking the router configuration I noticed that I had a wrong vlan configuration that result in this behavior.